# Python constructor arguments keeps changing?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Someone might be able to explain what is going on here. I've only started python today and it seems the constructor of my class is doing weird things.
This is my constructor:

```
def __init__(self, studentid, fname, lname, gpa):
    self.studentid = studentid
    self.fname = fname
    self.lname = lname
    self.gpa = gpa
```

When I call

```
    student = Student(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
```

it throws an error: TypeError: **init**() takes exactly 5 arguments (6 given)

yet when I call

```
student = Student(1, 2, 3, 4)
```

it throws this error: TypeError: **init**() takes exactly 5 arguments (8 given)

...?

Comment: Can you show the complete stack trace? Particularly for the `Student(1, 2, 3, 4)` version?

Comment: Thanks. I figured out the problem is not caused when I'm submitting the form but instead on the page redirect, cause by an error in a different function. Cheers!

Comment: your second call should work.

Comment: @CY5, can you clarify what you mean?

Comment: @CY5 I wish I could downvote your comment...that's not good advice.

Answer (score 3):

This is definitely has 5 arguments

```
def __init__(self, studentid, fname, lname, gpa):
```

The correct call to initialize a Student is

```
student = Student(1, 2, 3, 4)
```

`self` is passed implicitly (as the object is bound by that stage). Which brings the total to 5.

Your other error will not be coming from this `class`. Read the traceback carefully (or post it in your question) to see where the error about 8 arguments is actually from.

Answer (score 2):

`self` is passed over by python implicitly. It is advised to pass `keyword arguments`, while calling methods and functions, for readability.

`student = Student(studentid=1, fname='John', lname='Doe', gpa=4)`.